# Tradução faltante "put on hold"

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tradução

Encontrei numa mensagem de alerta nesse link:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75808/php-como-preencher-um-campo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu notei isso hoje também

Comment: O texto da caixa de status foi alterado recentemente, e "sobrescreveu" a tradução. Os moderadores estão tentando arrumar um jeito de melhorar essas traduções